# How to prevent layout from overlapping with iOS status bar

Tags: ios, react-native

I am working on [tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-navigators.html#content) for React Native navigation. I found out that all layout starts loading from top of screen instead of below of the status bar. This causes most layouts to overlap with the status bar. I can fix this by adding a padding to the view when loading them. Is this the actual way to do it? I don' think manually adding padding is an actual way to solve it. Is there a more elegant way to fix this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Navigator } from 'react-native';

export default class MyScene extends Component {
    static get defaultProps() {
            return {
                    title : 'MyScene'    
            };  
    }   
    render() {
            return (
                    <View style={{padding: 20}}> //padding to prevent overlap
                            <Text>Hi! My name is {this.props.title}.</Text>
                    </View> 
            )   
    }    
}
```

Below shows the screenshots before and after the padding is added.
[image]

Comment: Nice question, but perhaps you could trim down the images.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39300715/1540350 <- this answer will not just fix the problem mentioned here, but even give you the possibility to color the background of the status bar in iOS and Android.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is a very simple way to fix this. Make a component.

You can create a StatusBar component and call it first after the first view wrapper in your parent components.

Here is the code for the one I use:

```
'use strict'
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform} from 'react-native';

class StatusBarBackground extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={[styles.statusBarBackground, this.props.style || {}]}> //This part is just so you can change the color of the status bar from the parents by passing it as a prop
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  statusBarBackground: {
    height: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 18 : 0, //this is just to test if the platform is iOS to give it a height of 18, else, no height (Android apps have their own status bar)
    backgroundColor: "white",
  }

})

module.exports= StatusBarBackground
```

After doing this and exporting it to your main component, call it like this:

```
import StatusBarBackground from './YourPath/StatusBarBackground'

export default class MyScene extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <StatusBarBackground style={{backgroundColor:'midnightblue'}}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `MidnightBlue` is invalid, told by React Native: *Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `backgroundColor` supplied*

Comment: It should be `midnightblue`.

Comment: The iOS status bar is not a fix size. It can be larger when sharing Wifi or in a call.

Comment: How do I use this when using React navigation hookup with redux, all pages are either in a stack navigator or tab navigator (nested) and hook with redux

Comment: If you import the react native component "StatusBar" and then use:

`height: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : StatusBar.currentHeight,` instead of `? 20 : 0,` you get the same result on Android.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y True ... plus 20px is *always* wrong on 5.5" displays (which are 56 physical pixels / 3 displayPixelRatio = 18px) or iPhoneX (where it's 132 / 3 = 44px).

Answer (score 79):

Now you can use `SafeAreaView` which is included in React Navigation:

```
<SafeAreaView>
    ... your content ...
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Might be good to note that this component is included in `react-navigation` now by default.

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue of status bar overlap--I wrapped my app in SafeAreaView and my app still overlaps the StatusBar. It seems to be geared towards the iPhone X notch/rounded corners situation

Comment: You don't wrap your app in it, you wrap a screen in it.

Comment: Ohh, that's nice! I like that one.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo Not correct. Works fine on all iPhone devices, as long as it's > iOS 11.

Comment: @FellowStranger You're right. It's not strict to iPhone X.

Comment: @izikandrw Depending on your setup, there may be more than one SafeAreaView, one from react-native and another from react-native-safe-area-context, the later is the one being referred to here

Answer (score 38):

I tried a more simple way for this.

We can get the height of Status Bar on android and use SafeAreaView along with it to make the code work on both platforms.

```
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar, Platform } from 'react-native';
```

If we log out `Platform.OS` and `StatusBar.currentHeight` we get the logs,

```
console.log('Height on: ', Platform.OS, StatusBar.currentHeight);
```

Height on:  android 24 and 
Height on:  android 24

We can now optionally add margin/padding to our container view using

```
paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
```

The final code in App.js is below:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Hello World</Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried it on android and it's working. I cannot test it on iOS yet, but as i know what the SafeArea is on iOS, i'm pretty sure it should work there too.

Comment: *** This should be set to accepted answer ***
The other solutions here provide arbitrary fixed heights based on their own single test situation

Comment: A perfect answer but SafeAreaView is not applicable for the iPhone devices with version below 11

Comment: Worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Best One. Worked. Why are we checking for ios here ?

Answer (score 17):

@philipheinser solution does work indeed.

However, I would expect that React Native's [StatusBar](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#translucent) component will handle that for us.

It doesn't, unfortunately, but we can abstract that away quite easily by creating our own component around it:

./StatusBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar, Platform } from 'react-native';

// here, we add the spacing for iOS
// and pass the rest of the props to React Native's StatusBar

export default function (props) {
    const height = (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 0;
    const { backgroundColor } = props;

    return (
        <View style={{ height, backgroundColor }}>
            <StatusBar { ...props } />
        </View>
    );
}
```

./index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import StatusBar from './StatusBar';

export default function App () {
    return (
      <View>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#2EBD6B" barStyle="light-content" />
        { /* rest of our app */ }
      </View>
    )
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The `react-navigation` docs have a great solution for this. First off, [they recommend](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/) **not** to use the `SafeAreaView` included with React Native because:

> While React Native exports a SafeAreaView component, it has some
> inherent issues, i.e. if a screen containing safe area is animating,
> it causes jumpy behavior. In addition, this component only supports
> iOS 10+ with no support for older iOS versions or Android. We
> recommend to use the react-native-safe-area-context library to handle
> safe areas in a more reliable way.

Instead, they recommend [react-native-safe-area-context](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context) - with which it would look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Navigator } from 'react-native';
import { useSafeArea } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

export default function MyScene({title = 'MyScene'}) {
    const insets = useSafeArea();

    return (
        <View style={{paddingTop: insets.top}}>
            <Text>Hi! My name is {title}.</Text>
        </View> 
    )   
}
```

I would like to note that it's probably a better idea to use the `SafeAreaView` that this library offers though, since phones these days may also have elements at the bottom that can overlap UI elements. It all depends on your app of course. (For more detail on that, see the `react-navigation` docs I linked to in the beginning.)

Comment: this is deprecated

Comment: @AcauãPitta Please provide a source when you make claims

Comment: useSafeArea is deprecated according to the docs:
https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context#usesafearea.

They reccomend utilizing the useSafeAreaInsets hook.

Comment: Use this hook for cases where you need more flexibility, but if you don't, as you said, use SafeAreaView with the SafeAreaProvider as it's the cleanest solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way that works **for iOS**:

```
<View style={{height: 20, backgroundColor: 'white', marginTop: -20, zIndex: 2}}>
   <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content"/></View>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you combine SaveAreaView and StatusBar, you get it.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar
https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview

Just do this:

```
<SafeAreaView>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <StatusBar translucent={false} backgroundColor="#fff" />

    // Your dark magic here
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this by adding a padding to you navigation bar component or just ad a view that has the same hight as the statusbar at the top of your view tree with a backgroundcolor like the facebook app does this.

Comment: Is that height value fixed and does not change no matter what phone you have? If so, where can I find information about the correct specific value for iOS / Android?

Answer (score 0):

Just Simple User React native Default StatusBar to  achieve this funcationality.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar backgroundColor={Color.TRANSPARENT} translucent={true} />
    <MapView
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
      style={styles.map}
      region={{
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.015,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
      }}
    />
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer is applicable to Android emulators]
Hi, I have imported status bar from "react-native" and called it at the end of  block with status bar style set to auto and it worked for me, the code below is for reference:

```
    import { SafeAreaView,Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
    import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
    export default function App() {
    return (
<SafeAreaView style={styles.appContainer}>
  
  
  <View >
    <TextInput placeholder='Add your course goal' />
    <Button title="Add Goals" />
  </View>
  <View>
  <Text>List of goals..</Text>
  </View>
  <StatusBar style="auto" />
  </SafeAreaView>
   );
   }
```