# Is there a way of adding a navigation / status bar to a react.native WebView?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, webview

```
        <Modal transparent={false} animationType={"slide"} visible={this.props.isVisible}>
            <WebView
                source={this.getLandingUri()}
                scrollEnabled={true}
                startInLoadingState={true}
                onLoad={this.getLoadingIndicator}
                onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
            />
        </Modal>
```

I have been using a react.native WebView to prompt the user a login page, and now I would like to add a navigation / status bar that provides the user with a "Done" button, plus the current domain.

Here are two screenshots showing what I currently have (l) and what I would like to have (r).

[image]  . [image]

I couldn't find any relevant props on the WebView for rendering a status bar. Is this possible at all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599850/how-to-prevent-layout-from-overlapping-with-ios-status-bar

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You might want consider using react-navigation library, you can easily config the header title and the left, right element you want to place in the header with their [StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack).

Download the expo app and Try out here: https://expo.io/@react-navigation/NavigationPlayground, in your case, you can wrap your webview within a page under a StackNavigator and config its `navigationOptions`