# React Native: Keep status bar visible at all times

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm creating a cross platform app, and I want to make sure that the status bar for IOS and Android is always visible, and that the app doesn't render over it. For example in IOS, the app renders over the status bar but it's transparent so I can still see it. In Android the bar is visible by default I think.

What I want is that the app always renders just below it. So that nothing overlaps on the status bar.

I've tried `<StatusBar hidden={false} />`, but that doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent layout from overlapping with iOS status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599850/how-to-prevent-layout-from-overlapping-with-ios-status-bar)