# Top-Left of Storybook Navigator overlaps with the Notification bar of Android Emulator

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, storybook

I am creating a `storybook documentation of my custom App Components in 'react-native'`.

The problem is, the `top left of navigator` is overlapping with the `notification bar of android`.

Although I can fix the stories itself by margins and all but the navigator seems to have no fix.
I tried using `SafeAreaView from react-native` but it doesn't seem to fix it.

I have seen some similar issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599850/how-to-prevent-layout-from-overlapping-with-ios-status-bar) but they are for app code. Can anyone point out a fix for Storybook?

I am also attaching screenshot of the problem and the code where I am looking for a fix.

Screenshot [image]

Code:

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font'
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Storybook from './storybook'
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { SafeAreaView ,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const fetchFonts=()=>{
    return Font.loadAsync({

      'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
      'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')
    });
  };
 
  

function App(props) {
  const [dataLoaded,setDataLoaded] =useState(false);
    console.log('Data is Loadinggg...',dataLoaded)
  if(!dataLoaded){
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={fetchFonts} onFinish={()=> setDataLoaded(true)} onError={(err)=>{console.log(err)}}/> // donot proceed further until this is true -> render nothing
    );
  }
  else{
    return <SafeAreaView style= {styles.container} ><Storybook {...props}/></SafeAreaView>
  }
}
export default registerRootComponent(App);
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```

In place of `<SafeAreaView></SafeAreaView>` I am looking for a fix. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview) says,

**SafeAreaView  is currently only applicable to iOS devices with iOS version 11 or later.**

So what you can do is,

**OPTION 1**

```
import { View, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from 'react-native'; // At the top
```

Replace your return to this

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Storybook {...props} />
  </View>
);
```

And your stylesheet to this

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight // This wil give proper padding at the top
  },
});
```

---

**OPTION 2**

```
import { StyleSheet, StatusBar, Platform, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
```

Your return statement will be

```
return <SafeAreaView style= {styles.container} ><Storybook {...props}/></SafeAreaView>
```

and your stylesheet will be like this

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : StatusBar.currentHeight,
  },
});
```

Comment: Option 1 worked, wrapping around with view was a good idea and then marginTop StatusBar Height, it is platform independent. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, Do also know the reason why the left pane in web version of storybook keeps on loading infinite?