# Change status bar color with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, android-statusbar

I use a `DrawerNavigator` from react-navigation in my app. Without any customization, the Android status bar is blue, and not black.

I tried to do

```js
StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#000000');
```

but it only works for a few seconds, and then it goes back to blue. It seems that something I am using set the status bar color to blue. However, I tried to remove all dependencies and only keep react-navigation, and it still happens and the docs of react-navigation do not say anything about that.

**How can I set the status bar color to black with react-navigation ?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think there is any conflict between `react-navigation` and the `StatusBar`, but I think you should use the `<StatusBar>` component rather than the imperative API. There's a high chance this is due to a re-render of your app and it just switch back to the default, with a component declare, you ensure it won't happen.

```js
<StatusBar backgroundColor='blue' barStyle='light-content' />
```

You can even have multiple ones per route, to change it depending on the path. If you want to change it depending on the user and using `redux`, declare it in a connected component and pass the `backgroundColor`.

Comment: I also tried that but it has no effect. However I am not really sure where I am supposed to put this.

Comment: On your top level root component or top level `View`. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39300715/2054072) too that might help if you want to have it for both platforms.

Comment: Thanks! (Bounty can be awarded tomorrow). For readers: this does not work if you use NativeBase. See this page for a solution: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/323

Answer (score 6):

Like Aperçu said no  conflict between react-navigation and the StatusBar. Each screen should be able to set properties on the device's status bar, and the container defined in createNavigationContainer should get the options on state change, and apply them natively. try this for StatusBar for entire App.

```
const AppContent = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Secondary: { screen: SecondaryScreen },
});

const App = () =>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle="light-content"/> 
    // style the bar. barStyle is text and icon color od status bar.
   <AppContent />
 </View>;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableOpacity, View, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import styles from "../styles/Style";

class ProfileScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
        return {
            headerLeft: (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');
                }}>
                    <Icon name="menu" size={30} color="#fff" style={styles.burgerIcon}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
            title: 'My Profile',
            headerRight: (
                <Icon name={'edit'} size={30} color={'#fff'} style={styles.headerRightIcon}/>
            ),
            headerTintColor: "#fff",
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#8BC83D',
                height: 56,
                elevation: null
            }
        };
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.screenContainer}>

                <StatusBar
                    backgroundColor="#7CB236"
                    barStyle="light-content"
                />
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                    I amsecond reder
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const ProfileScreenList = StackNavigator(
    {
    ProfileScreenIndex: {screen: ProfileScreen},
}
);
export default ProfileScreenList
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid manually handling mounting and unmounting of screens by e.g. updating a redux state, you can also use react navigation's useIsFocused.

Let's say you want a single screen in a route to have a dark themed StatusBar:

```
import { StatusBar, View } from 'react-native';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function MyDarkScreen() {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();
    return (
        <View>
            {
                isFocused &&
                <StatusBar
                    barStyle={'dark-content'}
                    translucent
                    backgroundColor="transparent"
                />
            }
            <SomeOtherComponent />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting your DrawerNavigator config ?
Doc says that `contentOptions` allows you to customize the drawer content.

In the file where you define your `DrawerNavigator`, maybe your `router.js` file. You should create your Navigator as:

```
const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: MyHomeScreen,
        contentOptions: {
            inactiveBackgroundColor: '#000000',
        }
   },
});
```

Maybe this page will help you: [DrawerNavigator](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/docs/api/navigators/DrawerNavigator.md#contentoptions-for-draweritems)

Currently, your Drawer is certainly re-rendered at some point, that's why the color returns to blue.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I think that inactiveBackgroundColor is not supposed to control the color of the status bar.

Comment: Have you declared a StackNavigator in which you add your DrawerNavigator ? Because you can customize the HeaderStyle with the NavigationOptions there. First, I thought you wanted to change the color of the drawer background, but what you want is customize the header at the top of the screen, right ?

Comment: Neither the drawer background nor the header. I want to customize the status bar (http://www.gizmobolt.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Sony-Android-Lollipop-5.0-Status-Bar.png)

Answer (score 0):

On top of @Balthazar's answer, if you are using SafereaView then you might need to set the Status Bar color in your stylesheet like this:

```
SafeArea: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('black'),
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
 }
```

P.S. this code also detects the SafeAreaView in android devices with notch.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a screenWrapper around every screen and using the hook useRoute we can get the active screen name and change the style of the screen based on requirement.

```
    // create the component 'ScreenWrapper.js'

   import {useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';
   import { View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
   import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

   export const ScreenWrapper = ({ children }) => {
    const route = useRoute();
    useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
        switch (route.name) {
          case 'Welcome':
            StatusBar.pushStackEntry({ barStyle: 'light-content', 
    hidden:false });
            break;
          case 'Signup':
            StatusBar.pushStackEntry({ barStyle: 'dark-content', 
    hidden:false });
            break;
          default:
            StatusBar.pushStackEntry({ barStyle: 'light-content', hidden: 
    true });
        }
      }, []));

    // we are applying the background color to the component itself
   return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
        }}>
        <StatusBar/>
        {children}
      </View>
      );
  
     };

   // And wrap this screen wrapper to all your components
   // eg: 

   <ScreenWrapper>
   <Welcome/>
   </ScreenWrapper>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use this, plugin [navigationbar-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/navigationbar-react-native) !

1, Install plugin

```
npm i navigationbar-react-native --save
```

2, Using

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,Image,
  View, 
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import NavigationBar from 'navigationbar-react-native';
 
const ComponentLeft = () => {
  return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-start'}} >
       <TouchableOpacity style={ {justifyContent:'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Image 
          source={require('./img/ic_back.png')}
          style={{ resizeMode: 'contain', width: 20, height: 20, alignSelf: 'center' }}
        />
        <Text style={{ color: 'white', }}>Back Home</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
 
const ComponentCenter = () => {
  return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
       <Image
        source={require('./img/ic_logo.png')}
        style={{resizeMode: 'contain', width: 200, height: 35, alignSelf: 'center' }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
 
const ComponentRight = () => {
  return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end', }}>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white', }}> Right </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
 
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <NavigationBar 
          componentLeft     = { () =>  {<ComponentLeft />   }
          componentCenter   = { () =>  {<ComponentCenter /> }
          componentRight    = { () =>  {<ComponentRight />  }
          navigationBarStyle= {{ backgroundColor: ''#215e79'' }}
          statusBarStyle    = {{ barStyle: 'light-content', backgroundColor: '#215e79' }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your root component, you have to import

> StatusBar

You can follow the below code.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, StatusBar} from 'react-native';


const Home = () => {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
           <StatusBar backgroundColor="#44A72C" barStyle="light-content" />
           <Text style={{fontFamily: 'UniNeueRegular-Italic'}}>Home Screen</Text>
        </View>
        );
      };
export default Home;
```

Thanks!