# ReactNative StatusBar not changing color on each route and seems to not be doing anything

Tags: react-native, expo

I know I should be providing code, but at this time, none of my `StatusBar` code is active and the color is defaulting to the "background color" correctly for my initial sign in screen.  I had my `<StatusBar />` component at the top level of my app, but now, I need to change `StatusBar` color based on the route.
After [Reading the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326347/change-status-bar-color-with-react-navigation), it looks straight-foward enough since I am using a `Stack` nav.  I can leave in my top level & then add it as a nested `StatusBar` which gets rendered.  However, the color doesn't change at all.

Inside my ScreenView, i am adding:

```
      <StatusBar barStyle={'default'} backgroundColor={'green'} />
```

So I ripped out all of my `StatusBar` references, and the color still seems to be correct out of the box ‍♂️ on the initial page view route.

Any chance the `SafeAreaProvider` from Expo could be impacting it?

How else could the Status bar color be impacted?

I am using Expo SDK 46 + React Native 0.69.6

GIF: [image]

Something this simple couldn't be tricky to implement right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below given code snippet for changing status bar color on each forward and backward move of screens -

**Android only solution :**

```
import {useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';

//inside your functional component use useFocusEffect hook

useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
        StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content'); // 'light-content' is also available
         StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('white'); //add color code
        StatusBar.setTranslucent(true);
    }, []),
  );
```

Comment: I am getting warnings that setBackgroundColor, setTranslucent are only available on Android

Comment: Yes, setTranslucent will only work with Android. Either you remove it or ignore the warning. The first two lines regarding setting up Status bar will work for your purpose.

Comment: setBackgroundColor also is for android only? Based on their TS file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297291/how-to-set-ios-status-bar-background-color-in-react-native

hope this will be useful for iOS.

Comment: thanks i also think the Expo Status bar is not yet supported in SDK 46: https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-46/packages/expo-status-bar#installation-in-managed-expo-projects

Comment: link above worked, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I was never able to get that method working with Expo. Fortunately the imperative method still works:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('green');
StatusBar.setBarStyle(isDark ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content');
```

Comment: I am getting warnings that setBackgroundColor, setTranslucent are only available on Android