# StatusBar background color iOS React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, statusbar

Is there a method to set background color or transparent `Statusbar` on iOS?

"react-native": "0.54.2"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297291/how-to-set-ios-status-bar-background-color-in-react-native), it would be very helpful.

You could also use something like this:
`<StatusBar hidden={false} barStyle="light-content" />`

This will give you the following look in iOS

[image]

Comment: i'm using React Nativigation

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet so I am able to run it and solve the problem for you !,
I am also using react-navigation and it works well, I think there is no relation

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
<StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the rgba property, it holds 3 values, r stands for red g stands for green and b for blue. The a stands for alpha,  The alpha parameter is a number between 0.0 (fully transparent) and 1.0 (fully opaque).
A rgba value would look something like this ==>

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(34,32,225, .6)'
```

Comment: hi, <StatusBar backgroundColor='rgba(0,0,0, .6)' animated />
backgroundColor works only in android!