# Change status bar color on iOS and Android in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having some trouble with React Native. I have a screen where I need to have a custom header (with icons and more stuff), so in the `navigationOptions` I'll be using `headerTitle` instead of `title`.

The problem is, when using a `headerTitle`, the status bar is not included in the component. So I have something like this:

```
headerTitle: () => <MyHeader />
```

and then:

```
const MyHeader = props => {
  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', height: '100%', padding: 10, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Testing</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

And I get this:

[image]

I tried doing this:

[How to set iOS status bar background color in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297291/how-to-set-ios-status-bar-background-color-in-react-native)

But didn't work.

This is my intended result:

[image]

I can do it using `headerStyle` and `headerTitleStyle` in `navigationOptions` but then I can't use a custom component...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `headerStyle`

```js
const MyHeader = props => {
  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', height: '100%', padding: 10, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Testing</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: () => <MyHeader />,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
  };
```

### IOS

[image]

### Android

[image]

Answer (score 0):

simple . use StatusBarIOS component.

Comment: Actually, after some testing I found out I can use `headerStyle` AND `headerTitle` with a custom component and it still works!