# Change the status bar color on iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, statusbar

I'm trying to change the statusBar background color, but the property only works on Android. I tried all kinds of examples to try to modify it on iOS, but nothing has worked so far.
The last thing I tried is the best answer from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297291/how-to-set-ios-status-bar-background-color-in-react-native) Needless to say, it didn't worked either.

I'm currently working on Xcode 12 with the iOS 14 SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [react-native-safe-area-context](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context) instead `SafeAreaView` and customize it.

see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67511254/7965547)
.

[image]