# Hide status bar on react-native/navigation modal open

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

How to achieve the status bar showing in the "MyModal" header picture? I followed the exact documentation and steps, but in my project, the status bar is white and does not overlay the previous screen. I have also attached a picture of my status bar. I also tried  but no luck

Here's my code

```
<MainStack.Navigator >
<MainStack.Group>
    <MainStack.Screen
        name="HomeNavigation"
        component={HomeNavigation}
        options={{
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "white", elevation: 0, shadowOpacity: 0 },
            headerTintColor: "#966ded",
            headerTitleAlign: "left",
            title: "Home",
            headerRightContainerStyle: { marginRight: "2%" }
        }}
    />
    <MainStack.Screen name="Appointments" component={Appointments} options={{ gestureEnabled: false, headerShown: false, popGesture: false }} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="InstructorMain" component={InstructorMain} options={{ gestureEnabled: false, headerShown: false, popGesture: false }} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="Mainscreen" component={Mainscreen} options={{ gestureEnabled: false, headerShown: false, popGesture: false }} />
</MainStack.Group>

<MainStack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal'}}>

    <MainStack.Screen name="Address" component={Address} options={{ gestureEnabled: false, }} />

    <MainStack.Screen component={BuildMealModal} name="BuildMealModal" options={({ navigation }) => ({
        headerStyle: { elevation: 0, shadowOpacity: 0 },
        headerTitle: "",
        headerLeft: "",
        headerShown: false,
        gestureEnabled: true,

    })}
    />
</MainStack.Group>
</MainStack.Navigator>
```

Here the documentation which i follows:
https://appetize.io/embed/8bnmakzrptf1hv9dq7v7bnteem?autoplay=false&debug=true&device=iphone12&deviceColor=black&embed=true&orientation=portrait&scale=72&screenOnly=false&xDocMsg=true&xdocMsg=true&params=%7B%22EXDevMenuDisableAutoLaunch%22%3Atrue%2C%22EXKernelLaunchUrlDefaultsKey%22%3A%22exp%3A%2F%2Fexp.host%2F%40snack%2Fsdk.47.0.0-KOnGIBx7j2%22%2C%22EXKernelDisableNuxDefaultsKey%22%3Atrue%7D
[image: need to acheive this]
[image: My project]

Comment: What do you want to do *exactly*?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour remove the white style status bar from BookAppointment status bar

Comment: Do you want the status bar to be black? Actually, that's the only difference between the images you added above.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour yes kevin

Comment: See: [How to set iOS status bar background color in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39300715/14945696)

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour When the book appointment modal is open,  the background should look like the "mymodal" screen. as it overlays the previous screen. I already tried the Status bar color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254228/discussion-between-sukhwinder-saini-and-kevin-m-mansour).