# Status Bar backgroundColor is not effecting in my react native IOS platform

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, native

In react native I am using this code to show the status bar and its backgroundColor is black, "Color black is just an example", It's implemented on Android but didn't take any effect on iOS. What would be the reason?

[Here's my emulator which is not taking effect on the status Bar]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjtsh.jpg)

Comment: Did you check the answers in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297291/how-to-set-ios-status-bar-background-color-in-react-native?rq=2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.